# SQUID SERVER (or whatever) HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: proxy, https, centos, squid, port-forwarding

I am not too familiar with Squid or IPTABLES, I have an idea that this will work but I cannot find a good example via Google. In a nutshell, I am trying to mimic an SSL Accelerator. Like a Sonicwall... but without spending thousands of dollars on it.

I want setup a secure external connection over HTTPS and forward that connect as HTTP to an internal IP. I will explain in the shortest/easiest fashion possible.

```
CLIENT CONNECTS <--> HTTPS ENCRYPTS EXTERNAL CONNECTION (PORT 443) on external IP 123.456.789.012 <--> DATA IS FORWARDED (PORT 8080) TO INTERNAL IP 10.11.12.13.
```

Any help, I swear I am not being lazy, just really confused.

*P.S. This is on a centOS box, I am a FreeBSD guy, so that might be part of my struggle (the commands are a little different here).*

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into either of nginx, Apache with mod_proxy or pound.
Most prefer nginx, bit pound is also à good choice.

Answer (score 1):

Nginx configured as a reverse proxy would be a good choice for something like this. Install it on another server or VM and configure the Hosts section of the configuration (much like Apache) to serve up HTTPS requests for your desired hostnames. The only difference is that you will not have it serve up the requests directly, but will fetch them from your internal HTTP server and relay the request back to the original requester via HTTPS.

There's a good article on how to specifically set up an Nginx reverse proxy, including serving via SSL, here:  https://www.techandme.se/set-up-nginx-reverse-proxy/ 
Or, searching for "how to set up Nginx as a reverse proxy" will return many more.